# GUID of field/property 'ResourceTimesheetManageId'

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-server, project-online

How to identify the GUID of field 'Timesheet Manager', which is present in OData by name 'ResourceTimesheetManageId'? I don't want to know GUID of resource who is Timesheet Manager, I want to know GUID of this field 'Timesheet Manager'.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself Sharepoint Manager (or other free SharePoint browsing tool) it will allow you to browse through the properties of the site collection to the level of item/field and find the GUID.

Comment: Thank you Marek. How/where do i get SharePoint browsing tool. Does it work for SharePoint/Project Online also?

Comment: Also, is it safe to use any that kind of third party tool for data security?

Comment: Ok I have downloaded this one, https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb. Now in this, there is no specifically Timesheet Manager defined. How do I find that column. There is a column Manager Name. Is it same as Timesheet Manager?

Comment: Thank your Marek, I have searched throughout in this tool, but timesheet Manager is nowhere present. I have searched through solution given by Nils also below, but that also wan't much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get the id, or if a uid exists for that field. Traditionally, the databases for project server have not been documented, as we're supposed to use the API and not the connect directly to the draft or published database (which exist in on-prem installs). In both the reporting database (on-prem) and the rest api, UIDs are available for all custom fields, but not OOB fields.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen all the fields,lists, properties and whatever possible. But Timesheet Manager is present nowhere. I take that it is not possible to identify GUID of this field or it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

After having discussion with both the above users and I have tried both the solutions also, I have reached to conclusion that there is no GUID for this field 'Timesheet Manager' or it is not possible to identified, though almmost all the data is fetched using both the above tools. 
Anybody has some other knowledge on this, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Use [PnP](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/someSite
$l = Get-PnPList ListName
Get-PnPField -List $l FieldName | Select Id
```

Comment: how do I find GUID of Timesheet Manager field using this?

Comment: Well, you could list all fields, including `Id` (which is the guid of the field). The solution is essentially the same as the one above. Go have a look at the field and you'll see the id.

Comment: I have generated all fields, but field 'Timesheet Manager' is not present anywhere